# how to input a file as a variable in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi

I need to input the path of a file in shell script as a variable and use the file in the same script.Suppose the path is `/home/pi/dest/file` and i want to use the `file` as a variable.Can anyone tell me the syntax to open specified path file

Comment: Do you want to put the path in a variable? Or just the base name (`file`)? Or do you want to put the *file content* in a variable? Or is the problem getting the user to provide the path?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not clear. But you can see below what I understood;

```
basename /home/pi/dest/file
```

basename command will give you the last component of the path.